# Finding the infimum of the range of a certain non-negative function associated to a $ C^{*} $-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, inequalities, c-star-algebras, lower-bounds

Let $ A $ be a non-trivial $ C^{*} $-algebra and $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Setting $ \mathcal{D} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} A^{n} \setminus \{ (0_{A},\ldots,0_{A}) \} $, we can define a function $ f: \mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{R}^{+} $ by
$$
f(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\frac
{\displaystyle \left\| \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{j}^{*} a_{j}^{\phantom{*}} \right\|}
{\displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \| a_{j} \|^{2}}.
$$
Observe that $ \operatorname{Range}(f) \subseteq \left[ \dfrac{1}{n},1 \right] $. The upper bound of $ 1 $ is pretty obvious, and it is attained if we let $ a_{1},\ldots,a_{n} $ be equal to any non-zero element of $ A $. The lower bound of $ \dfrac{1}{n} $ is gotten as follows:

> Let $ (a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}) \in \mathcal{D} $. Then $ \displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{j}^{*} a_{j}^{\phantom{*}} \geq_{A} a_{k}^{*} a_{k}^{\phantom{*}} $ for every $ k \in \{ 1,\ldots,n \} $, which implies that
>   $$
>      \left\| \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{j}^{*} a_{j}^{\phantom{*}} \right\|
> \geq \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \| a_{k} \|^{2}.
> $$
>   Hence,
>   $$
>      f(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n})
> \geq \frac{\displaystyle \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \| a_{k} \|^{2}}
>           {\displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \| a_{j} \|^{2}}
> \geq \frac{\displaystyle \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \| a_{k} \|^{2}}
>           {\displaystyle n \cdot \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \| a_{k} \|^{2}}
> =    \frac{1}{n}.
> $$

I understand that this lower bound of $ \dfrac{1}{n} $ may be far from sharp, so my question is:

> **Question.** What is the infimum of $ \operatorname{Range}(f) $ in terms of $ n $? If this is totally unknown, then does anyone know of a better lower bound for the infimum than $ \dfrac{1}{n} $?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you asking for a lower bound valid for all C*-algebras? The lower bound $1/n$ is already attained in the $n\times n$ matrices; let $a_j$ be the projection onto the $j^{th}$ basis vector. It will also be obtained in commutative C*-algebras $C(X)$ as soon as $X$ contains at least $n$ points (just take any $n$ functions with disjoint supports). But then by the spectral theorem, as soon as $A$ contains a positive element with at least $n$ points in its spectrum, the $1/n$ bound is attained.

Comment: @Mike: Hi Mike. Thank you for your comment, which shows that $ \dfrac{1}{n} $ is the best universal lower bound. This is precisely what I was looking for!